# How can I count a specific variable in the code in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

HI

I understand that we can search specific word/Variable in VS2010 editor. For example, If I used a variable called (MyTest) and I want to count how many times I used this variable/word  in the code of say (10000) lines. 
If possible, how can we do it in the current form or count the word in all form the project?

Thanks!

Comment: Regarding variables - Do you want to count how often that *specific* variable is used, all variables in your project that have that name, or all occurrences of the text "MyTest" regardless of whether or not they references to variables or are inside strings or comments?

Comment: Yes, I wan to know how often a specific variable is used in the editor.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you wont to search for "MyVariable" press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and the Find/Replace Dialog should open. Enter "MyVariable" into the "Find what" field and again into the "Replace with" field. Set the Scope to "Current Document" and press the "Replace all" button. A message will popup telling "xxx occurrence(s) replaced.", where xxx is the number you are looking for.

Press the "undo"-Button once, if you want to revert the document-state to unchanged.

Comment: If you are worried that you will not be able to undo the changes you can always enter the replace phrase with the same as the search phrase

Answer (score 3):

Can you not highlight the variable and press Shift+F12?  This will tell you all of the matches found.

Comment: Or Right-click and choose "Find all references" - maybe his kb shortcut isn't working

Comment: The short-cut didn't work?  If that is the case, right mouse click the variable and then click Find All References.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the text "MyTest", here is a hacky way to do it.

1. Use the find dialog (CTRL F) to search for the text. You can modify the scope. eg Document, project etc
2. Click `Bookmark all`
3. Then open the Bookmarks window (`View-Bookmark window`) to see a list of all the bookmarks. It doesn't show the total number but you could easily count them manually here.

Answer (score 1):

1. `Ctrl + Shift + F` to pull up the Find in Files dialog
2. Enter your search variable name and scope (document, project, solution etc)
3. `Find all`
4. Scroll to the bottom of the resulting `Find Results` and you'll see `Matching lines: xxx`

[image]

Comment: This is the exact solution , all other solutions in the page are complex or wrong.